# запрет исполнения диапазона файлов .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Есть несколько файлов .

```
exampletext1.php
exampletext2.php
exampletext3.php
exampletext4.php
```

Как с помощью `.htaccess` запретить чтение/исполнение всех файлов - 
в имени которых есть `"exampletext"` чтобы не пришлось запрещать каждый файл.

что - то вроде этого но не для конкретных файлов , а для тех в имени которых присутствутет `"exampletext"`

```
<Files exampletext.php>
      Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1):

[RTFM же](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#filesmatch)! В документации к Apache аналогичный пример рассмотрен подробнейшим образом:

> The `<FilesMatch>` directive limits the scope of the enclosed directives
>   by filename, just as the `<Files>` directive does. However, it accepts a
>   regular expression. For example:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
    # ...
</FilesMatch>
```

> would match most common Internet graphics formats.
>
> The `.+` at the start of the regex ensures that files named `.png`, or
>   `.gif`, for example, are not matched. From 2.4.8 onwards, named groups
>   and backreferences are captured and written to the environment with
>   the corresponding name prefixed with `"MATCH_"` and in upper case. This
>   allows elements of files to be referenced from within expressions and
>   modules like mod_rewrite. In order to prevent confusion, numbered
>   (unnamed) backreferences are ignored. Use named groups instead.

```
<FilesMatch "^(?<sitename>[^/]+)">
    require ldap-group cn=%{env:MATCH_SITENAME},ou=combined,o=Example
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: это не совсем ответ

Comment: А что это по-вашему, вопрос? Впрочем, вы вольны считать как угодно.

Comment: ну четкого кода , который решает задачу вы не написали , я знаю что существует документация apache, но если бы у меня было время на то чтобы сесть и внимательно читать документацию я бы так и сделал :)

Comment: Ну вроде как тут задают вопросы , и получают конкретные ответы на них , никто не просит расжовывать ничего , вы могли бы просто написать по примеру который я предоставил выше , и все были бы довольны

Comment: По примеру есть в моём ответе (то есть в документации апача). Ровно то, что и требуется в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

```
<FilesMatch "exampletext">
      Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

`exampletext` - это не просто текст, а регулярное выражение, просто в данном вопросе так сложилось.

Comment: спасибо , этот код будет выполнять то что я перечислил сверху?
сейчас проверю

Comment: Только надо заметить, что здесь будет запрет на все файлы, в имени которых есть подстрока `exampletext`, а не только строго на `exampletext*.php`

Comment: да я знаю , мне именно это и нужно

Comment: Вот что ответил мне сервер :) 500 Internal Server Error
Внутренняя ошибка сервера

Comment: Удалил все строки в .htaccess , написал только ваш код , всеравно увы не работает , что - то с кодом

Comment: А что у вас с `AllowOverride`?

Comment: Извините, виноват. Указал неправильный закрывающий тэг, поэтому была ошибка 500

Answer (score 0):

После того как изучил документацию Apache по совету и наводке Pink Tux , спасибо ему за это , нашел код который мне подошел , правда он отличается от вышеперечисленных.

```
<Files "exampletext??">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Это для файлов, которые начинаются с exampletext, или этот текст может быть в любом месте названия?

Comment: проверено  , это для файлов который начинаются с exampletext , но внивательно ! эти 2 вопроса говорят что вместо них могут быть любые 2 символа , если хотите чтобы было неограниченное количество символов , воспользуйтесь кодом который я написал выше , вместо знаков вопроса - один знак звездочки

Comment: можете переставить звездочку если надо чтобы файл заканчивался этим exampletext

Answer (score 0):

вот окончательный работающий вариант , спасибо документации apache и `Pink Tux` за наводку

```
<Files "exampletext*">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
</Files>
```